# findViewById returns null in getView of adapter

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Im trying to understand why findViewById always returns null when Im reusing my view in getView() of my custom adapter.

1) Below image shows my ListView. Pretty basic.

[image]

2) I have defined another xml file called selected_apps_button.xml which is view that'll be added to the ListView above. Here is the image

[image]

3) Here is how im inflating the view in step 2 to add to the ListView in step 1

```
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View selectAppsButton = convertView;

    if(selectAppsButton == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        selectAppsButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_apps_button, parent, false);
    }


    final TileButton appColorButton = (TileButton) selectAppsButton.findViewById(R.id.appColorr);
    final TileButton appNameButton = (TileButton) selectAppsButton.findViewById(R.id.appNamee); //appNameButton is always null
```

4) In the above code 'appNameButton' is always null. Interesting thing is 'appColorButton' from same inflated layout is NOT null.

5) Any idea what's going on?

I have build and rebuild the project like a million times. But it didnt help.

Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks.

Comment: What is `selected_apps_button`?  `findViewById(...)` only finds children of the view it's called on.

Comment: @kevin: selected_apps_button is the name of XML file. Second image is that file. It has a linear layout.

Comment: What do your `TileButton` constructors look like?

Comment: @laalto here it is 

`public TileButton(Context context) {
  super(context);
  associatedData = new SerializableButtonData();
 }

 public TileButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        associatedData = new SerializableButtonData();
 }

 public TileButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
        associatedData = new SerializableButtonData();
 }`

Comment: could you post the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: @Blackbelt there is no exception. 
`final TileButton appNameButton = (TileButton) selectAppsButton.findViewById(R.id.appNamee); //appNameButton is always null`
Above line always returns null.